# Knockout Error for click

Tags: knockout.js

I am beginner in knockout, while doing samples I got  error message while trying to browse my page.

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: ItemToEdit is undefined

below is my code:

```
 $(function () {
     countries = [{
         name: France
     }, {
         name: Germany
     }, {
         name: Spain
     }];

     var viewmodel = {
         table: ko.observableArray(countries),
         ItemToEdit: function () {
             var editedItem = ko.dataFor(this);
         },
     };
 });
```

My HTML :

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click :ItemToEdit">Edit</a>
```

Comment: can you please post a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call `applyBindings`, it binds your view model to html. Add the following line after creating vm:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating over `table` in a `foreach` binding or the like, then `ItemToEdit` won't be in your current context but its parent context (which in this case is also the root context) instead. Thus you'll have to qualify it:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click : $parent.ItemToEdit">Edit</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click :$root.ItemToEdit">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Artem is saying, you need to call `ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);` within the function you pasted:

```
 $(function () {
     countries = [{
         name: France
     }, {
         name: Germany
     }, {
         name: Spain
     }];

     var viewmodel = {
         table: ko.observableArray(countries),
         ItemToEdit: function () {
             var editedItem = ko.dataFor(this);
         },
     };
     ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
 });
```

You're probably calling `applyBindings` somewhere outside that function which would mean it can't find `viewmodel`.